# Multiple Rendering Issue on Google Chrome when Adding Elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm seeing an issue in Chrome where when using jQuery to remove and add elements to the page, the elements are being rendered twice. They are rendered once correctly and then rendered again over top of themselves but slightly offset.

When you resize the window afterwards the issue disappears, or sometimes doesn't show up at all at certain window sizes.

This seems to be a bug that has cropped up in one of the recent versions of Chrome in both Windows and Mac. Doesn't happen in Firefox, Safari for Mac or IE10 on Win7.

What would be the proper way to stop this from happening? Is there something wrong with my javascript?

It happens on the following page, when switching locations using the links on the left hand side:

http://affordableattic.com/locations/#donna

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of multiple rendering issue in Chrome]

Here is the jQuery where I replace the elements in question on the page:

```
if(locationPhoto.indexOf("crystal/default.png") < 0){
  currentItem = '<div class="streetview"><img src="' + locationPhoto + '" alt="' + locationAlt + '" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-605"></div>';
}

if(mgrPhoto.indexOf("crystal/default.png") < 0 && mgrPhoto != "false"){
  currentItem += '<div class="storemanager"><img src="' + mgrPhoto + '" alt="' + mgrAlt + '" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-592" />';
  currentItem += '<span class="caption"><!--googleoff: all-->' + mgrCaption + '<!--googleon: all--></span></div>';
}

if(tabletLinks || mobile){
  address = '<a href="' + mapLink + '">' + address + '</a>';
}
if(mobile){
  phone = '<a href="tel:1-' + phone + '">' + phone + '</a>';
}

currentItem += '<div class="clear"></div><h2>' + title + '</h2><div class="contact">';
currentItem += '<p><i class="icon-map-marker icon-2x pull-left"></i>' + address + '</p>';
currentItem += '<p><i class="icon-phone icon-large pull-left"></i> ' + phone + '</p>';
if(truckRental != ''){ currentItem += '<p><i class="icon-phone icon-large pull-left"></i> ' + truckRental + '</p>'; }
currentItem += '<p><i class="icon-envelope-alt pull-left"></i>  <a href="mailto:' + email + '?Subject=' + emailSubject + '">' + email + '</a></p>';
currentItem += '<div class="buttons">';
currentItem += locationText;
currentItem += '</div>';
currentItem += '<div class="clear"></div></div>';

iconTime = '<p><i class="icon-time icon-large pull-left"></i>';

currentItem += '<div class="hours">';
currentItem += iconTime + mon + '</p>';
currentItem += iconTime + tues + '</p>';
currentItem += iconTime + wed + '</p>';
currentItem += iconTime + thu + '</p>';
currentItem += iconTime + fri + '</p>';
currentItem += iconTime + sat + '</p>';
if(sunD != "" ){ currentItem += iconTime + sunD + '</p>'; }
currentItem += '</div>';

currentItem += '<div class="buttons standalone">';
currentItem += locationText;
currentItem += '</div>';

container.fadeOut('slow', function()
{
  container.hide().empty().html(currentItem).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

If you'd like to see the full script let me know. There are a couple other things going on such as maps and hashchange.

Comment: Try removing the fade animations to see if that is the cause.

Comment: Oddly enough if I leave my mouse on the link I get the double render, but the second i trigger a hover animation for one of the other links the second render disappears.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why, but it seems to have something to do with the fade. Clear the screen so it doesn't show the double render, then run this from your console -    jQuery('#locations-container').hide().fadeIn('slow');    - It causes the double render to be recreated. I also tried changing your script from .fadeIn() to .animate({'opacity': 1}), but it caused the same issue. When using purely .hide() and .show() it does not have a double render. Again, I'm not sure why, but the animation is causing it.

Comment: @wrxsti Thanks very much for your help! I won't have time to try this fix til after lunch and will come back when I do to let you know the results.

Comment: FYI, this seems to do the trick: `jQuery('#locations-container').hide().fadeIn('slow', function(){ jQuery('#locations-container').html(jQuery('#locations-container').html()) });`

Comment: @Malk Thank you very much -- that worked perfectly and I can still have the content fade in after loading! If you want to post this as an answer I will select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @wrxsti Thank you that fixes the problem but I went with Malk's solution as I was able to keep the fade in animation that way.